# Class CacheItemPoolInterface not Found Symfony

Tags: php, symfony, api-platform.com

I am using api-platform and Symfony. It works perfectly in local, but when I deploy it on the PREPROD server I the following error.

I have no idea at all what the problem is. I take any hints Thank!

> Invalid service "cache.app": class Psr\Cache\CacheItemPoolInterface
>   not found.

[image]

Here is my composer :

```
{
    "type": "project",
    "license": "proprietary",
    "require": {
        "php": "^7.1.3",
        "ext-iconv": "*",
        "api-platform/api-pack": "^1.1",
        "erc/pdfmerger": "^0.0.1",
        "setasign/fpdf": "1.8.1",
        "symfony/console": "^4.0",
        "symfony/flex": "^1.0",
        "symfony/form": "^4.0",
        "symfony/framework-bundle": "^4.0",
        "symfony/lts": "^4@dev",
        "symfony/monolog-bundle": "^3.2",
        "symfony/yaml": "^4.0"
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "symfony/dotenv": "^4.0",
        "symfony/web-server-bundle": "^4.0"
    },
    "config": {
        "preferred-install": {
            "*": "dist"
        },
        "sort-packages": true
    },
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "App\\": "src/"
        }
    },
    "autoload-dev": {
        "psr-4": {
            "App\\Tests\\": "tests/"
        }
    },
    "replace": {
        "symfony/polyfill-iconv": "*",
        "symfony/polyfill-php71": "*",
        "symfony/polyfill-php70": "*",
        "symfony/polyfill-php56": "*"
    },
    "scripts": {
        "auto-scripts": {
            "cache:clear": "symfony-cmd",
            "assets:install --symlink --relative %PUBLIC_DIR%": "symfony-cmd"
        },
        "post-install-cmd": [
            "@auto-scripts"
        ],
        "post-update-cmd": [
            "@auto-scripts"
        ]
    },
    "conflict": {
        "symfony/symfony": "*"
    },
    "extra": {
        "symfony": {
            "allow-contrib": false            
        },
        "public-dir": "www"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the error is thrown due to your production config depending on [Symfony Cache component](https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/cache.html).

Try *explicitly* requiring it:

`composer require symfony/cache`

If you get the message that it's already *implicitly* installed, it's probably disabled in production environment.